# Waiting for a response from Chrome native messaging application before sending headers

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension, chrome-native-messaging

I have a Chrome extension which comprises of a content script and a background script. I use the background script to communicate with the Chrome native messaging application and use the code below to pass the message received message from this application to the content script:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, message);
});
```

The message is received in the function below in the content script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (response, sender, sendResponse) {

});
```

How can I change the headers of HTTP requests using data from the Chrome native messaging application? Since `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` is async, the function that I will modify the headers 
 (`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener`) will not wait for it.

Comment: You can't do it in Chrome.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve a similar effect by e.g., `sleep()`?

Comment: No, there's no sleep in JS, it's single-threaded.

Comment: What about `async`, `await`? Can they be used to solve this?

Comment: No, async/await is just a syntactic sugar, it doesn't change the fact that webRequest listener must return the result synchronously.